# Create table with effective_from_date and effective_to_date from history table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update, dbt, scd

I have a table in which data gets appended for the changes. No delete or update, only append is done by a cloud run job.

Base table

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Last_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 394 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 939 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 345 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 837 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |
| 123 | ABC | 03 478 102 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 |

I'd like to create another table like below.

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Effective_From | Effective_To | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 394 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 | N |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 345 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 | N |
| 123 | ABC | 03 478 102 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 | 9999-12-21 00:00:00 | Y |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 939 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 | N |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 837 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 | 9999-12-21 00:00:00 | Y |

What would be the best way to achieve? I was trying to find a way to do this using dbt but unable to find any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below query for reference and create your model in dbt

```
    with raw as (
    select 
    '123' as Supplier_ID, 'ABC' as Supplier_Name, '03 483 394' as Supplier_Contact, cast('2023-05-01 12:34:56' as datetime) as Last_Modified
    union all 
    select 
    '124' as Supplier_ID, 'ABD' as Supplier_Name, '02 848 939' as Supplier_Contact, cast('2023-05-01 12:34:56' as datetime) as Last_Modified
    union all
    select 
    '123' as Supplier_ID, 'ABC' as Supplier_Name, '03 483 345' as Supplier_Contact, cast('2023-05-02 10:45:05' as datetime) as Last_Modified
    union all
    select 
    '124' as Supplier_ID, 'ABD' as Supplier_Name, '02 848 837' as Supplier_Contact, cast('2023-05-02 10:45:05' as datetime) as Last_Modified
    union all
    select 
    '123' as Supplier_ID, 'ABC' as Supplier_Name, '03 478 102' as Supplier_Contact, cast('2023-05-08 11:09:15' as datetime) as Last_Modified
    ),
    raw2 as (
    select Supplier_ID,Supplier_Name,Supplier_Contact,Last_Modified as Effective_From,lead(Last_Modified) OVER (partition by raw.Supplier_ID ORDER BY raw.Supplier_ID,raw.Last_Modified asc) as Effective_To   from raw order by raw.Supplier_ID,raw.Last_Modified asc
    )
    select *EXCEPT(Effective_To),ifnull(raw2.Effective_From,'9999-12-21 00:00:00') as Effective_To,
if(raw2.Effective_To is null, 'Y','N') as is_active
 from raw2
```

Comment: How I can implement this with the dbt incremental strategy? My table size would keep increasing and would be better to have incremental updates rather than whole table refresh each time. Currently the table is of size 7 million and it would keep growing each day.

Comment: you can keep just active_records='Y' why do you need all the records is there any specific reason @AshokKS

Comment: I want them since I need to pass a date in the past and get which records were active during that period. So for example if i want to know the Supplier_Contact as of 5th October I could pass the date as a between clause for effective_from and effective_to columns.